# Situations where "come before" and "go before" are interchangeable

Tags: word-usage

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/a-an-and-the)

> A/an and the are articles. They are a type of determiner and they go before a noun.

According to which, I could say

> Articles **go before** a noun.

From a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/uU-RbEEolw0?t=52)

> Articles are a challenging part of speaking English but they're a really
> important part. They give information about the noun that they come before.

So, I could also say

> Articles **come before** a noun.

I completely understand the meaning of those sentences. I would just like to figure out the situations where "come before" and "go before" are interchangeable.

"come before" and "go before" are interchangeable in this situation, right? Is there any other situations where "come" and "go" are interchangeable?

Comment: There is a specific equivalence between the verbal *phrases* ***go before*** and ***come before***. Without the addition of *before*, ***come*** and ***go*** would almost never be interchangeable. You can't analyze the single words on their own in this context. Another pair of verbal *phrases* like this is ***come here*** and ***go here*** (in the context of pointing to a place on a map, for instance).

Comment: It's like "A slim chance" or "fat chance". Yes they're antonyms, but in one specific example, they're interchangeable (in this case, because "fat" is used sarcastically).

Answer (score 0):

One basic difference between the two (*come* and *go*) is that **come** signifies motion toward the speaker:

> Hey, James! Come here.

and **go** signifies either general motion or motion away from the speaker:

> Go away! Stop disturbing me!

But just like Jason Bassford said in the [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/248616/situations-where-come-before-and-go-before-are-interchangeable#comment467375_248616), without **before**, they can almost never be used interchangeably.